# How to merge multiple rows in time series data having same time into a single record using scripting in Linux?

Tags: linux, awk, sed, time-series

I have a time series data wherein measurement values from different sensors have been captured asynchronously and concatenated into same ascii file. The sensor values have been captured at the same time instance.

The values are white space separated.

Original file looks like below.

```
2022 281 08 48 14 876 10                1.00       NOTSAMPLED          NOTSAMPLED
2022 281 08 48 14 876 10          NOTSAMPLED             0.00          NOTSAMPLED
2022 281 08 48 14 876 10          NOTSAMPLED       NOTSAMPLED                1.00
2022 281 08 48 15 391 11                1.00       NOTSAMPLED          NOTSAMPLED
2022 281 08 48 15 391 11          NOTSAMPLED             0.00          NOTSAMPLED
2022 281 08 48 15 391 11          NOTSAMPLED       NOTSAMPLED                1.00
2022 281 08 48 15 896 12                1.00       NOTSAMPLED          NOTSAMPLED
2022 281 08 48 15 896 12          NOTSAMPLED             0.00          NOTSAMPLED
2022 281 08 48 15 896 12          NOTSAMPLED       NOTSAMPLED                1.00
```

Now I need to replace the string `NOTSAMPLED` with the previous instance sensor value as mentioned below and also merge sensor values spread across multiple rows and columns into single row having same time.

```
2022 281 08 48 14 876 10                1.00       0.0     1.0
2022 281 08 48 15 391 11                1.00       0.0     1.0
2022 281 08 48 15 896 12                1.00       0.0     1.0
```

Similarly if input data is

```
2022 281 08 48 14 876 10                1.00       NOTSAMPLED          NOTSAMPLED
2022 281 08 48 14 876 10          NOTSAMPLED             0.00          NOTSAMPLED
2022 281 08 48 14 880 10          NOTSAMPLED       NOTSAMPLED               10.00
2022 281 08 48 15 391 11                1.00       NOTSAMPLED          NOTSAMPLED
2022 281 08 48 15 391 11          NOTSAMPLED             0.00          NOTSAMPLED
2022 281 08 48 15 395 11          NOTSAMPLED       NOTSAMPLED               11.00
2022 281 08 48 15 896 12                1.00       NOTSAMPLED          NOTSAMPLED
2022 281 08 48 15 896 12          NOTSAMPLED             0.00          NOTSAMPLED
2022 281 08 48 15 900 12          NOTSAMPLED       NOTSAMPLED               12.00
```

then my expected output is

```
2022 281 08 48 14 876 10                1.00             0.00          NOTSAMPLED
2022 281 08 48 14 880 10                1.00             0.00               10.00
2022 281 08 48 15 391 11                1.00             0.00               10.00
2022 281 08 48 15 395 11                1.00             0.00               11.00
2022 281 08 48 15 896 12                1.00             0.00               11.00
2022 281 08 48 15 900 12                1.00             0.00               12.00
```

How can it be achieved using sed/awk or any other bash shell scripting commands ?

I tried the following script.

```
#! /bin/bash

inp_filename=$1

awk '
NR == 1 { split($0, filldown) }
{
 for (i = 6; i <= NF; i++)
  if ($i != "NOTSAMPLED")
   filldown[i] = $i
 else
   $i = filldown[i]
 print
}
' $inp_filename`
```

But the result is

```
2022 281 08 48 14 876 10 1.00 NOTSAMPLED NOTSAMPLED
2022 281 08 48 14 876 10 1.00 0.00 NOTSAMPLED
2022 281 08 48 14 876 10 1.00 0.00 1.00
2022 281 08 48 15 391 11 1.00 0.00 NOTSAMPLED
2022 281 08 48 15 391 11 1.00 0.00 NOTSAMPLED
2022 281 08 48 15 391 11 1.00 0.00 1.00
2022 281 08 48 15 896 12 1.00 0.00 NOTSAMPLED
2022 281 08 48 15 896 12 1.00 0.00 NOTSAMPLED
2022 281 08 48 15 896 12 1.00 0.00 1.00
```

Comment: please update the question with the code you've tried and the (wrong) output generated by your code

Comment: do you need to maintain the same spacing as displayed or is a single space (or tab) sufficient? are the entries *always* in sets of 3 and if not then what should we do if less than 3 rows are provided (ie, a sensor reading is missing)? within a given set of rows (w/ same date/time stamp) is it possible to have more than 1 non-NOTSAMPLED value and if so which value should be used to generate the final result?

Comment: @markp-fuso Spacing can be more than a single space or a tab. The entries need not be in sets of 3. It depends on the time stamps of sensors. And the number of sensors can be more than 1 and not only 3. Suppose there are 4 sensors out of which 2 sensors have same time. Then for that same time, the remaining 2 sensors should either show NOTSAMPLED if any value has not been measured, otherwise it should retain the previously measured value until there is a new value.

Comment: @markp-fuso. I tried `awk '
    BEGIN { getline; split($0, filldown); print }
    {
        for (i = 3; i <= NF; i++)
            if ($i != "NOTSAMPLED")
                filldown[i] = $i
            else
                $i = filldown[i]
    } 1
' file.txt` from an earlier post. It is removing NOTSAMPLED with previous instance value for the same sensor. But additionally I need to merge sensors which have same time.

Comment: please update the question with your code attempts (not everyone will read through comments trying to piece together the whole picture; code is harder to read/understand in a comment); I would also suggest you update the sample data to include a set of data for, say, 2 sensors and 4 sensors (making sure to update the expected output, too)

Comment: in comments you've mentioned several cases that are not demonstrated by your sample inputs; you'll increase your chances of getting a workable solution if your sample inputs cover all of the cases you've touched on in the comments; the question should be updated to include these additional cases along with a brief description of the said cases; the expected output should then be updated to correspond with the expanded set of inputs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One `awk` idea:

```
awk '
function print_values(  j) {
    if (FNR>1) {
        printf "%s", ts_prev                # print previous date/time stamp
        for (j=8;j<=NF;j++)                 # loop through sensor values and append to current line of output
            printf "%s%s", OFS, (values[j]=="" ? "NOTSAMPLED" : values[j])
        print ""                            # terminate current line of output
    }
    ts_prev = ts_curr
}
    { gsub(/\r/,"")                         # per comment from OP, need to remove windows/dow line endings
      ts_curr=$1                            # save date/time stamp of current line
      for (i=2;i<=7;i++)
          ts_curr = ts_curr FS $i

      if (ts_curr != ts_prev)               # if this is a new date/time stamp then ...
          print_values()                    # print previous date/time stamp and associated sensor values

      for (i=8;i<=NF;i++)                   # loop through values and ...
          if ($i != "NOTSAMPLED")           # if a valid value then ...
             values[i]=$i                   # save the value
    }
END { print_values() }                      # flush last date/time stamp to stdout
' sensor.dat
```

This generates:

```
2022 281 08 48 14 876 10 1.00 0.00 NOTSAMPLED
2022 281 08 48 14 880 10 1.00 0.00 10.00
2022 281 08 48 15 391 11 1.00 0.00 10.00
2022 281 08 48 15 395 11 1.00 0.00 11.00
2022 281 08 48 15 896 12 1.00 0.00 11.00
2022 281 08 48 15 900 12 1.00 0.00 12.00
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can it be done using bash script also ?

Comment: before you editted your comment you posted (in your comment) the output generated when this code was run in your system;  from that output it appears your input file contains windows/dos line endings; you can see this with `head -3 filename | od -c` and you should see lines ending with the sequence `\r \n`; you have a couple options ... remove the `\r` characters before running `awk` (eg, `dos2unix filename` - only need to run once as this will update the file), or you can modify the code to dynamically remove `\r` characters ...

Comment: I've updated the answer to remove the `\r` characters; please run the code again to see if you now get the desired output; as for the question about doing it in `bash` ... probably doable but I'll leave that up to someone else to address; alternatively, if you understand how this `awk` code works you should be able to convert it to comparable `bash` code; since the question (as currently written) appears to be geared towards an `awk` solution, and all answers (so far) are `awk`ish in nature, I'd suggest if you have problems converting this answer to `bash` that you ask a new question

Answer (score 1):

This will fill "NOTSAMPLED" with the valid sample value of the same column in the preceding row. The first few (3) rows remain unchanged, as there is no preceding sampled value.

```
awk -v ns=NOTSAMPLED '
BEGIN {a[0]=ns; a[1]=ns; a[2]=ns}
{
    for (i=0; i<3; ++i) {
            if ($(NF-i) == ns) {
                    $(NF-i) = a[2-i]
            }
            else {
                    a[2-i] = $(NF-i)
            }
    }
    print
}' myfile
```

This fills fields with no *preceding* value (near the start) with the closest *proceeding* value. It parses the file twice - once to gets the first three sampled values and again to fill in the same manner as the previous example.

```
awk -v n="NOTSAMPLED" '
FNR==NR && filled != 3 {
    for (i=0; i<3; ++i) {
            if ($(NF-i) != n && a[2-i] == "") {
                    a[2-i] = $(NF-i)
                    ++filled
            }
    }
    nextline
}
FNR!=NR {
    for (i=0; i<3; ++i) {
            if ($(NF-i) == n) {
                    $(NF-i) = a[2-i]
            }
            else {
                    a[2-i] = $(NF-i)
            }
    }
    print
}' myfile myfile
```

The output delimits all columns with a single space. If you want the longer whitespace, just change `print` to `printf` with an appropriate format string (like `printf "...%20s%20s%20s\n", ...,$8,$9,$10`)

Explanation:

- Scanning each row, keep an array of the most recent valid samples for each column.
- Replace `NOTSAMPLED`, with the value from the array. If a field *is* valid, instead update the corresponding array element.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The solution is giving correct result. Can it be extended to more than 3 columns ?

Comment: Sure. Change the `3` in the for loop (`i<3`) and in `filled != 3`, _and_ change the 2 in`a[2-i]`. Eg. change to to `i<4`, `filled != 4` and `a[3-i]` to fill the last 4 columns instead of the last 3 columns. You could use a variable. Also, in the first example, you need to add the extra default values to the array in `BEGIN`.

Comment: Also, `NF-i` is "last field minus i" so it's iterating backward (left) from the last field. You can change `NF-i` to `N-i`, or `N+i` to scan backward or forward, respectively, from the Nth field (instead of backward from NF/last field). Hope that helps.